# What service UUIDs are required to work with TI SensorTag?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

In iOS, the call `[CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralWithServices:options:]` lets you specify a service `UUID` to select a `BLE` peripheral. What service `UUID` can I use to discover a `SensorTag`?

Here's a code example:

```
- (void)startScan {
    NSDictionary *options = @{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES };
    // This UUID doesn't work.
    NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"]];

    [self scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:options];
}
```

Comment: Put nil, check what service it advertises in its advertisement data (see the `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback method) and then you can use an array of services filtering the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Although the SensorTag has a service UUID F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000, I didn't have any luck scanning for it that way.  I had to scan like so:

```
  [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

and then loop through the services to see if the peripheral had what I want.  As a side note, I have been unable to update the firmware on my SensorTag and would hope that they eventually fix this problem.

Comment: If the Sensor tag does not advertise the service with the UUID you mentioned, that's normal. It may have them, but you can discover them only if you connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the TI example application's source code here: http://www.ti.com/tool/sensortag-sw The iOS example contains exactly what you are looking for.

Otherwise, you can scan with `nil` services and examine (simplest to print out) the `advertisementData` when you receive the `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback. The keys corresponding to services will tell you what the peripheral advertises and you can use those to narrow down the scan.